# About java-rest-binding

Tags: neo4j

I want to use neo4j in rest way with Java. In this case, should I use java-rest-binding(https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding)? 
I cannot find javadoc comments in the source code, so where can I get the java-rest-binding API documentations? How can I use java-rest-binding more easily? Is there any sample code? I am checking out the test cases in the source code for reference. I am doing this right way? give me some suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: There are no information about java-rest-binding at the language driver page (http://www.neo4j.org/develop/drivers). What does it mean? They(Neo Technology) don't want developers to use it(java-rest-binding)?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at http://thought-bytes.blogspot.in/2013/07/getting-started-with-neo4j-java-rest-heroku.html and http://thought-bytes.blogspot.in/2013/07/neo4j-java-rest-binding-part-2-batching.html if it helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author